# Python: reading from binary zipfile into csv

Tags: python-3.x

Old `python 2.7` contained the code that worked:

```
import zipfile
import csv

myzip = zipfile.ZipFile('archive.zip')
csv_data = csv.reader(myzip.open('db_file.csv', 'r', 'password'), delimiter=',')
for rowData in csv_data:
  ...
```

I need to make it working with `python 3.5`.
`csv.reader` now requires password as bytes instead of old string -> adding `b'password'`
and as a result it returns `csv_data` also as bytes.
`csv.reader` is waiting for a string.
Is there some "elegant" or "out-of-the-box" way to convert bytes to string directly into csv or do I have to iterate over the strings by hands with `line.decode('ascii')` for each? (I've used such approach for a simple txt file from the same archive with a password)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `io.TextIOWrapper` https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper

You might need to encode the password, if you have encrypted files, but the handle is decoded on the fly by `TextIOWrapper`. You also might need to adjust encoding, to the one used by your file.

For example, this works for my simple `csv` file.

```
import zipfile
import csv
import io

myzip = zipfile.ZipFile('archive.zip')
with io.TextIOWrapper(myzip.open('db_file.csv', 'r'), encoding='ascii') as z:
    csv_data = csv.reader(z, delimiter=',')
    for rowData in csv_data:
        ...
```

Comment: Great! This is directly what I need. Thank you very much.